# Exception in Text Analysis depending on length of a chosen value of JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jcombobox, actionlistener

I'm very surprised of this superior site!

My Goal is to get a .txt-file, read it in, cut it in single strings depending on which "windowsize" is chosen (how many characters, chosen by a jcombobox) and list it by frequency.
With debugging, it stops where the comment is marked.
I can't eliminate those thrown exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xxxx.Babbles_GUI.windowSize(Babbles_GUI.java:247)    at
xxxx.Babbles_GUI.actionPerformed(Babbles_GUI.java:203)  at
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6375)    at
javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)  at
java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6140)    at
java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)    at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4737)   at
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)   at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)   at
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
    at
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)    at
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2482)     at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)   at
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:684)  at
java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:657)   at
java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:655)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:654)   at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

### Code

```
public class Analysis {

    /**
     * @param file
     */
    public static void analyze(File file, int windowSize) {
        ArrayList<String> splittedText = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(windowSize);

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis,
                        Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buf.append(line);
                    splittedText.add(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String wholeString = buf.toString();

        // for (int i = 0; i < wholeString.length(); i += (Babbles_GUI
        // .WindowSize())) {
        // splittedText.add(wholeString.substring(
        // i,
        // Math.min(i + (Babbles_GUI.WindowSize()),
        // wholeString.length())));
        // }

//      for (int i = 0; (i < wholeString.length()-(Babbles_GUI.WindowSize())); i += Babbles_GUI.WindowSize()) {
//          splittedText.add(wholeString.substring(i, Math.min(Babbles_GUI.WindowSize()+i, wholeString.length())));
//      }

        for(int i = 0; i<wholeString.length()-(windowSize); i++){
            splittedText.add(wholeString.substring(i, i+windowSize));
        }
        System.out.println("error");

        Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(splittedText);
        for (String key : unique) {
            Babbles_GUI.txtAnalysis.append(Collections.frequency(splittedText,
                    key) + "x  " + key + "\t" + "\t");

        }
        Babbles_GUI.txtLog.append("Text analyzed with WindowSize "
                + windowSize + "\n");

    }
}
```

#### Babbles_GUI

```
public class Babbles_GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JFileChooser fc1;
    JButton btnFileCh;
    JButton btnOutput;
    JLabel lblBtnLabel;
    static JTextArea txtLog;
    static JTextArea txtOrig;
    static JTextArea txtAnalysis;
    JTextArea txtGenerated;
    static JComboBox cbxWindowSize;
    BorderLayout borderlayout;
    JScrollPane ScrLog;
    private JPanel pnWest;
    private JPanel pnEast;
    private JPanel pnNorth;
    private JPanel pnCenter;
    private JPanel pnSouth;

    static int numberofchars;

    public Babbles_GUI(String title) {

        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setSize(1200, 2400);
        this.createUI();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocation(
                (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width - this
                        .getSize().width) / 2, (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                        .getScreenSize().height - this.getSize().height) / 2);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void createUI() {

        btnFileCh = new JButton("Open...");
        // btnFileCh.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnFileCh.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        btnFileCh.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        btnFileCh.addActionListener(this);

        lblBtnLabel = new JLabel("Number of letters to shuffle: ");
        lblBtnLabel.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblBtnLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        txtLog = new JTextArea();
        txtLog.setBackground(getBackground());
        txtLog.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        txtLog.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        txtLog.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtLog.setLineWrap(true);
        txtLog.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        JScrollPane spTxtlog = new JScrollPane(txtLog);
        spTxtlog.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        spTxtlog.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5, 0, 0, 0,
                Color.RED));

        txtOrig = new JTextArea();
        txtOrig.setEditable(false);
        txtOrig.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtOrig.setLineWrap(true);
        txtOrig.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        txtOrig.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        txtOrig.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        txtOrig.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 0, 0, 0,
                Color.BLUE));

        txtAnalysis = new JTextArea();
        txtAnalysis.setEditable(false);
        txtAnalysis.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtAnalysis.setLineWrap(true);
        txtAnalysis.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        txtAnalysis.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        txtAnalysis.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        txtAnalysis.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 0, 0, 20));
        JScrollPane spTxtAn = new JScrollPane(txtAnalysis);
        spTxtAn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 0, 0, 0,
                Color.GREEN));

        btnOutput = new JButton("Generate");
        btnOutput.addActionListener(this);
        btnOutput.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnOutput.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        btnOutput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));

        String[] item = { "WindowSize 1", "WindowSize 2", "WindowSize 3",
                "WindowSize 4", "WindowSize 5", "WindowSize 6", "WindowSize 7" };
        JComboBox cbxWindowSize = new JComboBox(item);
        cbxWindowSize.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        cbxWindowSize.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        Box bxLeft = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        bxLeft.add(lblBtnLabel);
        bxLeft.add(cbxWindowSize);

        Box bxCenter = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        bxCenter.add(btnFileCh);

        Box bxRight = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        bxRight.add(btnOutput);

        txtGenerated = new JTextArea();
        txtGenerated.setEditable(false);
        txtGenerated.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        txtGenerated.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        txtGenerated.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 0, 0, 0,
                Color.YELLOW));

        pnWest = new JPanel();
        pnEast = new JPanel();
        pnNorth = new JPanel();
        pnCenter = new JPanel();
        pnSouth = new JPanel();

        pnWest.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pnWest.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 10));
        pnWest.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        pnEast.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pnEast.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 0));
        pnEast.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        pnNorth.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        pnNorth.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        pnCenter.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pnCenter.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        pnSouth.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        try {
            this.fc1 = new JFileChooser();
            fc1.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(null, "txt"));

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            txtOrig.append("");
            txtLog.append("File format must be .txt" + "\n");

        }
        pnNorth.add(bxLeft);
        pnNorth.add(bxCenter);
        pnNorth.add(bxRight);

        pnSouth.add(spTxtlog, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pnWest.add(txtOrig, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pnWest.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 700));

        pnCenter.add(spTxtAn, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pnCenter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 700));

        pnEast.add(txtGenerated, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pnEast.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 700));

        borderlayout = new BorderLayout();
        borderlayout.setHgap(30);
        borderlayout.setVgap(3);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        getContentPane().setLayout(borderlayout);
        getContentPane().add(pnEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
        getContentPane().add(pnWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
        getContentPane().add(pnNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(pnCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(pnSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == btnFileCh) {
            int returnVal = fc1.showOpenDialog(Babbles_GUI.this);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc1.getSelectedFile();
                txtLog.append(file.getName() + " opened" + "\n");
                printOrigFile(file);
                //DEBUG-STOP**********************************
                Analysis.analyze(file, windowSize());
            } else {
                txtLog.append("Open command cancelled by user" + "\n");
            }
            txtLog.setCaretPosition(txtLog.getDocument().getLength());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Babbles_GUI("Babbles Exercise David Huser");

    }

    /**
     * @param file
     * @return
     */
    public String printOrigFile(File file) {

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis,
                        Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buf.append(line + "\n");
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        txtOrig.setText(buf.toString());
        return (buf.toString());
    }

    public int windowSize() {
        if (cbxWindowSize.getSelectedItem().equals("WindowSize 1")) {
            numberofchars = 1;
        } else if (cbxWindowSize.getSelectedItem().equals("WindowSize 2")) {
            numberofchars = 2;
        } else if (cbxWindowSize.getSelectedItem().equals("WindowSize 3")) {
            numberofchars = 3;
        } else if (cbxWindowSize.getSelectedItem().equals("WindowSize 4")) {
            numberofchars = 4;
        } else if (cbxWindowSize.getSelectedItem().equals("WindowSize 5")) {
            numberofchars = 5;
        } else if (cbxWindowSize.getSelectedItem().equals("WindowSize 6")) {
            numberofchars = 6;
        } else if (cbxWindowSize.getSelectedItem().equals("WindowSize 7")) {
            numberofchars = 7;
        }
        return numberofchars;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is line 247 in the source?  Alternatively, post the entire .java file.  Also, your highlighting is off - try indenting the first lines of the methods and classes, etc...

Comment: 247:  public int windowSize() {

Comment: Oh my!  Line 247 of one of several public classes.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  And please use the code formatting tags (select the code and click the `{}` button above the message posting/editing form) when posting code **or** exceptions and other input/output.

Comment: Thank you, I'll consider this for sure the next time. I formatted the exceptions.

Comment: Yes, but you both 'unanonymised' the package and ruined the code formatting I'd done on the code itself.  I'm about to roll back your edit, please leave it to me for the moment.  :)

Comment: oh sh*t, sorry!!
the package would be
`package ch.fhnw.icb.huser.david.babbles;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an object that is null in `windowSize()`. Are you sure `cbxWindowSize` is initialized?

The other possibility is that there is no selected item. `getSelectedItem()` will return null in that case. You need to check this instead of immediately calling `equals()` on the result.

**Edit:**

```
String[] item = { "WindowSize 1", "WindowSize 2", "WindowSize 3",
            "WindowSize 4", "WindowSize 5", "WindowSize 6", "WindowSize 7" };
JComboBox cbxWindowSize = new JComboBox(item);
```

This defines a new local variable and initializes it. The local variable is hiding the class variable with the same name. Remove `JComboBox` from the beginning of the line.

Comment: yes. cbxWindowSize is Null right now.
but I initialize it in the constructor?
`static JComboBox cbxWindowSize;
String[] item = { "WindowSize 1", "WindowSize 2", "WindowSize 3",
    "WindowSize 4", "WindowSize 5", "WindowSize 6", "WindowSize 7" };
  JComboBox cbxWindowSize = new JComboBox(item);`